# How to call $resource query method with query string

Tags: angularjs, query-string

I have written:

```
 $scope.myResource= $resource("rest/myResources/:id", {id:'@id'},
    {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false , paramDefaults:{page: '1', sort:'name,desc'}}});
```

But when I call `$scope.myResource.query` angular sends `GET` request with URL `localhost:8080/myapp/rest/myResources` without any query string.

All I need is to add `page` and `sort` parameters. How can I do that?

**P.S.** I have already tried to change `paramDefaults` to `params` it did not help

Comment: Works fine here with `params`: http://plnkr.co/edit/4hWw0GBZwlk5DnGttFOk?p=preview